# Using PatIndex and CharIndex like the InStr function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, patindex, charindex

I tried using `Instr` for this, but didn't work, so I found the supposed to be equivalent using `PatIndex` and `CharIndex`, however, I'm having an issue here when I run this:

```
SELECT PATINDEX(`http://www.stackoverflow.com`,'%.com%')
```

This returns `0`

---

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(`http://www.stackoverflow.com`,'%.com%')
```

This returns `0`

---

```
SELECT PATINDEX(`http://www.stackoverflow.com`,'.com')
```

This returns `0`

---

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(`http://www.stackoverflow.com`,'.com')
```

This returns `0`

---

How do I get this to work like `InStr` ?

If my calculation is correct, it should return `25` instead of `0`, anyone know why it's not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it reversed.

```
select patindex('%.com%', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
select charindex('.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful while using those functions in computed column functions. Because they are non-deterministic.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214775(v=sql.80).aspx